# Dynamically re-bind html.ValidationMessageFor html helper?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Some background information, I am using ASP.NET with the MVC framework and html helpers.

I currently have a dynamic table where each row has a series of input boxes. Each of these input boxes has a validation message. This works completely fine for the first row. However, when other rows are dynamically added (with the IDs' being changed along with other attributes to match the row number) the validation message no longer works.
Both the row and validation message span are being replicated properly.

In JQuery, this is usually just a problem with the binding, so for each row I would simply re-bind the IDs'. However I am not really to sure how to approach them in ASP.NET.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are the dynamically-added rows' inputs being given the same name/id values as the first row's, or do they each have their own name and value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I have finally figured this out.

In MVC, in order to handle the validation, it import a JQuery file known as jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js.
However, similar to JQuery, this only occurs at the very beginning when the page is loaded. So, when you add a new dynamic element, you need to remove the bindings and the re-bind them again.

Basically, in your function for adding a new element, put the following lines of code AFTER you have added the new element:

```
$("#form").removeData("validator");
$("#form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#form");
```

For example:

```
function addInfoDynamic()
{
    document.getElementById("#myDiv").innerHTML += "New Content";

    $("#form").removeData("validator");
    $("#form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#form");
}
```